# Regex for visa cards - exclude results with special symbols in front of the number

Tags: regex

I am trying to make regex which can match visa card numbers. I want to catch the number if it has symbols in the end like ", ; space, etc." however i want to skip the number if these symbols are in front of it.

Example: 
4716068046194035, ,4716068046194035,

If i have the row above i want to match only 4716068046194035,

So far i'm using this one

\b4\d{15}[\,\;\|\s]

but i cannot exclude the second number with comma in front of it.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you read this: http://www.regular-expressions.info/creditcard.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution using [String.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) function with specific regex pattern:

```js
var str = '4716068046194035, ,4716068046194036, 4716068046194037, ,4716068046194038',
    cards = str.match(/(?:^|[^,])4\d{15}[ ,;]?\b/g);

console.log(cards);
```

`(?:^|[^,])` - alternative group, ensures that a number sequence is at the very start of the string OR is not preceded by `,`

`[ ,;]?` - allowed characters a number sequence can be followed by